# Sending push notifications to app in limited setup - fake_push_profile not found Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification

I have followed the instructions to setup a limited setup for push notifications at this article: http://docs.ionic.io/v2.0.0-beta/docs/push-limited-setup

I've got a device ID, and I've registered an API token with Ionic. I have the app running in my browser and am attempting to run

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "tokens": ["DEV_DEVICE_TOKEN"],
    "profile": "fake_push_profile",
    "notification": {
        "message": "Hello World!"
    }
}' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

In a bash console. However I'm getting an error that looks like this:

```
"error": {"link": null, "type": "BadRequest", "message": "Security Profile 'fake_push_profile' not found."}}
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. Have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got the solution.

You need to create a `Profile` in your `app` Dashboard.

Navigate to : [Your app setup Page Online](https://apps.ionic.io/app/2b856d5c/config/credentials)

Create a profile and Name it `fake_push_profile` .

In your `.sh` file from your where your are sending push you need to enter `fake_push_profile` in your `profile` key:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer Your_Token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"tokens": ["Device_Token"],
"profile": "fake_push_profile",
"notification": {
    "message": "Hello World!"
}
 }' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

That's all you need to do.

Here is the screenshot what I did and it works like a charm.

I did it for `iOS`.

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! One question though, would limited push only work in the browser? Or is there a way of it working on android for testing purposes as well. I have checked out the Caveats of limited push and it says nothing about apps. So would it work in combination with ionic view or?

Comment: @5parc Limited push will work everywhere...web/android/ios you dont need any configuration for it....I have implemented in ionic..and is working fine with andoid and ios as well

Comment: Can't get it to work sadly, I am trying to get my phones device ID using jsconsole without much success. Any tips, because I really want push notifications to work for phone, I am also using full push now.

Comment: @5parc You are developing for android or ios ?

Comment: @5parc have you `ionic config set dev_push false` run this command ? and what issue exactly you are facing. Push in ionic is little bit tricky. For me it takes complete 3 days to make it work.